# How to export text file data to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I want to export the text file data into MySQL database

```
import MySQLdb
import re

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "123456")
mycursor =conn.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  EMP")
mycursor.execute("USE  EMP")
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp_details  (Id VARCHAR(255) , Firstname VARCHAR(255),Lastname VARCHAR(255),department VARCHAR(255),salary VARCHAR(255)) ")

f = open("new.txt", "rb")
print (f.next())

for x in f:

  mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO emp_details VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",x)
  conn.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

I am getting an error

```
query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

[this is what my text file data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH8OC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Split your line on comma as you must provide 5 arguments to that execute string. Also, you should explicitly name those columns:

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO emp_details (Id, Firstname, Lastname, department, salary) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x.split(","))
```

Comment: ```query = query % args
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
``` 
this error is coming up now

Comment: Probably some line in your file isn't formatted well. Either inspect your data file or truncate that file to few lines only, try if code works for that sample and then inspect your file.